# Rails 3.2, No Route Matches { :controller=>'xxx' :action=>'xxx" }

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to edit multiple records with a checkbox form as shown in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple).  Rails has changed since then and I'm having trouble with routing and forms.

I have a PeopleController and I'm trying to make a form that will edit all of their phone numbers at once.  Yes, I know this isn't a useful function, as there is normally no reason to change everyone's phone numbers to the same thing, but I'm just using this to get comfortable with the code - and it isn't working!

Here's what I've got:

people_controller:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @people = Person.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @people }
    end
  end

  # GET /people/1
  # GET /people/1.json
  def show
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @person }
    end
  end

  # GET /people/new
  # GET /people/new.json
  def new
    @person = Person.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @person }
    end
  end

  # GET /people/1/edit
  def edit
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /people
  # POST /people.json
  def create
  ...
  end

  # PUT /people/1
  # PUT /people/1.json
  def update
  ...
  end

  def update_multiple
    @people = Person.find(params[:people_ids])
    @people.each do |person|
      person.update_attributes!(params[:person].reject { |k,v| v.blank? })
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Updated people"
    redirect_to people_path
  end

  # DELETE /people/1
  # DELETE /people/1.json
  def destroy
  ...
  end

  private

  def sort_column
    Person.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end

end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing people</h1>
<% form_tag edit_multiple_people_path do %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "phone" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "created_at" %></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @people.each do |person| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "people_ids[]", person.id %></td>
    <td><%= person.name %></td>
    <td><%= person.phone %></td>
    <td><%= person.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', person %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_person_path(person) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', person, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<% # submit_tag "Edit Checked" %>
<% end %>
<br />

<%= link_to 'New Person', new_person_path %>
```

edit_multiple.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :person, :url => update_multiple_path, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
  <ul>
    <% @people.each %>
      <li>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "people_ids[]", person.id %>
        <%=h person.name %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Routes.rb:

```
  resources :people do
    collection do
      put 'update_multiple'
    end
  end
```

And rake routes:

```
update_multiple_people PUT    /people/update_multiple(.:format) people#update_multiple
                people GET    /people(.:format)                 people#index
                       POST   /people(.:format)                 people#create
            new_person GET    /people/new(.:format)             people#new
           edit_person GET    /people/:id/edit(.:format)        people#edit
                person GET    /people/:id(.:format)             people#show
                       PUT    /people/:id(.:format)             people#update
                       DELETE /people/:id(.:format)             people#destroy
```

**EDIT:**

My routes were messed up.  They are now working properly as shown above.

Comment: Thanks @zeantsoi, you were a big help.  Not only for the question, but for Stackoverflow netiquette!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating singular and plural resources. The `edit_multiple_path` route is currently configured as a singular resource, meaning that it expects a single `Person` to be passed as an argument. However, by definition, you're trying to update multiple people at a single time – it doesn't make sense to use a singular route, in this case.

Instead, try a [collection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) route:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :people
    collection do
        post 'update_multiple/:people_ids', :action => 'update_multiple'
    end
end
```

This will make the following route available:

```
       update_multiple_invites POST   /invites/update_multiple/:people_ids(.:format) invites#update_multiple
```

EDIT:

In the index view, you'll need to output your forms in order for them to be displayed:

```
# app/views/people/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag edit_multiple_people_path do %>

# app/views/people/_edit_multiple.html.erb
<%= form_for :person, :url => update_multiple_people_path, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
```

Note that `<% %>` interprets everything enclosed within, but does not output it. You need to use `<%= %>` in order to actually output the form's contents.

Also, don't forget that your partial needs the extension `.erb` in order for it to interpret Ruby code. Perhaps you've named it accordingly, but your post depicts the name `edit_multiple.html` *without* the `.erb`.

Comment: This cleaned up my paths nicely, but as in my comment reply to @Talgat my index is no longer displaying my records.

Comment: The routing error was solved with your answer before editing, thanks! I updated my original question with the routes.rb and rake routes working properly.

Comment: Updated my answer. Also, as an FYI, you don't need the edit_multiple collection route, since you don't have any action to route to/from it.

Answer (score 0):

On `submit` take a look at the code inspector and verify if you are getting routed to an `GET` request.

If you are getting a 404 that results in a GET request instead of a PUT request, it's because the `:method => :put` option relied on JavaScript. You'll need to make sure `jquery-rails` is properly integrated in your app.

Comment: When trying to go to localhost:3000/people I'm just getting:

Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"people", :action=>"edit_multiple"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

So I can't check it.

Comment: Ok, open the `Developer Tools` if you are on Google Chrome and check the `Network` tab on the `submit` action.

Comment: You're right, 404. My Gemfile has gem 'jquery-rails' in it... Can you point me in the right direction to make sure it's properly integrated?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get this route:

> No route matches {:controller=>"people", :action=>"edit_multiple"}

but in route.rb you are including :id attribute witch is requred

> people/:id/edit_multiple

So in form you need to include person id

try out following code to get this route {:controller=>"people", :action=>"edit_multiple"}

```
resources :people do               
 collection do         
  get :edit_multiple       
  put :update_multiple       
 end        
end
```

Comment: I removed :id and now I get the page but without any of the people I previously added being listed.

'Listing people


New Person'

Comment: Before it wasn't loading my index page, now it is, but the submit button isn't showing, along with the records.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting routed to correct action.

@Emrys, what kind of error displayed in index page?

Comment: There's no error displayed.  It just isn't showing me anything inside the form. Just the `<h1>Listing People</h1>` and the `New Person` link are displayed.