# Contents of my Rails 3 form not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

For some reason the contents of this form are not displaying.  It is the standard index generated by the rails scaffold, but I enclosed it in a form to add a checkbox for a multi edit.

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing people</h1>
<% form_for edit_multiple_people_path do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "phone" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "created_at" %></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "people_ids[]", person.id %></td>
        <td><%= person.name %></td>
        <td><%= person.phone %></td>
        <td><%= person.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', person %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_person_path(person) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', person, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag "Edit Checked" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'New Person', new_person_path %>
```

All that is displaying when I go to the page is:

```
Listing People

New Person
```

Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Your form looks ok. Just debug @people.

Comment: It works fine without the form there.

Comment: @Emrys, welcome to SO! Hope you're finding the community useful and are developing an interest in contributing. As a reminder, if a question has effectively addressed your question, you should consider accepting and/or voting it up. It's considered both helpful and polite to do so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: try     <%= form_for @people, :url => edit_multiple_people_path do %>

Comment: Thanks @zeantsoi, I've actually attempted to do so, but I don't have the 15 rep points necessary to upvote answers yet.

Comment: @Emrys, you may not be able to _upvote_, but you can and should _accept_ the answer you found to be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499207/rails-3-2-no-route-matches-controller-xxx-action-xxx):**

In the index view, you'll need to output your forms in order for them to be displayed:

```
# app/views/people/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag edit_multiple_people_path do %>

# app/views/people/_edit_multiple.html.erb
<%= form_for :person, :url => update_multiple_people_path, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
```

Note that <% %> interprets everything enclosed within, but does not output it. You need to use <%= %> in order to actually output the form's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<%= form_for` instead of `<% form_for`